# How to use Excel's index/match function in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Pls let me know how to use Excel's index/match function in Pandas.

```
'''
      Name Score
U-01    A   1
U-02    A   1
U-03    A   1
U-01    B   2
U-02    B   2
U-03    B   2
'''

'''
       U-01 U-02 U-03
A_SCORE  X   X   X
B_SCORE  X   X   X

'''
```

I want to fill the blanks(X)
111
222
with Pandas.

Thanks for your help!
Please help me,,

Comment: Use [`df.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = {'code': ['U-01', 'U-02', 'U-03', 'U-01', 'U-02', 'U-03'],
        'name': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
       'score': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

pt = df.pivot(index='name', columns='code', values='score')

print(pt)
```

Output:

```
code  U-01  U-02  U-03
name
A        1     1     1
B        2     2     2
```

Comment: thank you so much! I resolved this problem!!